# How can I make a background with a left and right image border that repeats?

Tags: html, css

This is probably a very common question. However I have tried to use every answer on the web, but for some strange reason there seems to be a clash in my stylesheet.
I have a background with an image (cloth) pattern that repeats over the full content.
Now I am trying to add one left and right border image (with threads, to make it look like a realistic cloth) to #container2, that repeats vertically down. But every time I do this, the whole container moves down, and when I adjust the position, it disappears.

The code I have is as following:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="container2">
<div id="header">

....................content...............

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { background: #323232 url(images/container-bg.png) repeat; position: relative; }
#container2 { background:  url(images/container-bg-right.png) repeat; min-height: 300px; padding: 0px 0 0px 3%; max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 5% 0 5%; }
#header { margin-bottom:50px; }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anyway you can create a http://jsfiddle.net for us to look at?

Comment: You don't need to set `repeat` in your CSS background property, as it's repeated by default.

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ There are some css3 commands you could use here if you're willing to. 

Why did you position: relative the #container? Are both backgrounds the same width? Is one wider than the other?

Comment: You said you are trying to add `border-image` property to `#container2` but your css has no such property. How are you adding it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your for you reply. Please have a look at the example at http://www.elmargasimov.com/. Basically what I am trying to do is add http://www.elmargasimov.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/images/threads-left.png and http://www.elmargasimov.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/images/threads-right.png on a vertical repeat (repeat-y) to the left and right side of container2. But every single time I do that, for some reason the whole container2 moves down.

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple images for your backgrounds *warning this isn't support by all browsers just yet*

So your html could be:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inset-borders">
    -- Content --
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#inset-borders {
  background-image:url('left-border.png') left repeat-y, url('right-border.png') right repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Intereting is there something like this also, do you have a link for any tutorial

Comment: the CSS3 multiple backgrounds has more support than I thought. It will probably be a good solution for you. A proper tutorial for you refhat: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want:

```
<div id="container"> </div>
<div id="container2"> </div>
<divid="header"> </div>
```

Or do you want "container2" inside of "container"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please have a look at the example at http://www.elmargasimov.com/. Basically what I am trying to do is add http://www.elmargasimov.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/images/threads-left.png and http://www.elmargasimov.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/images/threads-right.png on a vertical repeat (repeat-y) to the left and right side of container2. But every single time I do that, for some reason the whole container2 moves down.

Comment: Try making the "Border" as your background for the entire page in you body tag.  Then set the "conatiner" background.  This way you don't have to float anything. And the "border" will be where ever the conatiner isn't.